# Padding between UITableViewCell and its subview (UICollectionViewCell)

Tags: ios, uitableview, subview

I've been futzing around trying to get some padding between the bottom of my subview and its container UITableViewCell. I have an xib file, but changes to that don't seem to affect my actual ui (i've had to pragmatically change the tableviewcell height, for example).

I've also tried a few examples on SO regarding adjusting the center value of the subview, but no cigar.

Any ideas?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I decided to just move the individual elements within the inner cell which is less reusable than just adjusting the whole cell, but.. It will do for now!

Cheers.